# Extending the analogy between cyclotomic units and elliptic units

Tags: elliptic-curves, l-functions, iwasawa-theory

There is a nice analogy between cyclotomic units and elliptic units given as follows:

1. Cyclotomic units are related to special values of the Riemann Zeta function. This is because the logarithmic derivatives of the Coleman series of cyclotomic units are linked to zeta values.
2. Elliptic units are related to special values of Hecke $L$-functions. This is because the logarithmic derivatives of the Coleman series of elliptic units are linked to Hecke $L$-values.

This analogy was used by Coates-Wiles in their paper "On the Conjecture of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer", where they proved a result about BSD for CM elliptic curves.

*My question is*: If $E/\mathbf{Q}$ is an elliptic curve, and $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character, can we extend this analogy to study the special values $L(E, \chi, 1)$? More precisely, are there any "units" (analogous to cyclotomic units and elliptic units) such that the logarithmic derivatives of power series (analogous to Coleman series) attached to those units are related to the special values $L(E, \chi, 1)$?

Comment: You should read about Euler systems, in particular Kato's Euler system. I recommend Rubin's book Euler Systems as a starting point